# Colocar barra no final da url com .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewrite

Preciso adicionar uma barra (/) ao final da url usando .htaccess.

Meu .htaccess atual está assim:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio.com.br [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.dominio.com.br/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-]+)/?$ /$1.html [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Viva,

No meu caso eu uso assim:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Abraço ;)

Answer (score 0):

Resolveu? Se não, eu uso assim:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```