# Como fazer Urls Amigaveis estilo instagram

Tags: php, htaccess

Fiz uma URL AMIGAVEL só que é o seguinte: queria que o link ficasse assim: `www.site.com/usuario1/`, ou seja, quando o cara coloca `www.site.com/usuario1` ele fosse redirecionado para o `www.site.com/usuario1/`.

Meu `.htaccess` é esse e só funciona se colocar sem a barra no fim `www.site.com/usuario1`

Tem como complementar esse htaccess para o exemplo acima?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) profile.php?id=$1/ [QSA,L]
```

Sim quero que fique com a / no final do nome do usuário, modifiquei o .htaccess para esse conforme foram falando por vocês:
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\..+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule (.*) /site/profile.php?id=$1/ [R=301,L]
```

funcionou até o redirecionamento, agora o links ficam:
site.com/profile.php?id=Usuario1/ é quero assim site.com/Usuario1/, o redirecionamento funcionou agora só a parte do profile.php?id=Usuario1 ficou errado.

Comment: @DiegoF não acho que é duplicada, o problema não é como fazer uma URL amigável mas sim quando o utilizador coloca uma barra no fim.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114168/colocar-barra-no-final-da-url-com-htaccess

Comment: @Gleyson se sua pergunta não for respondida por nenhum dos links indicados, edite-a explicando o que precisa de diferente, e o que não funcionou nas respostas indicadas para o seu caso (mas antes, consulte aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/htaccess que tem uma quantidade imensa de perguntas sobre .htaccess  e "URL amigável' já respondidas no site).

Comment: @Bacco editei adicionei informações.

Comment: Como meu voto de fechamento é instantâneo, votei pra reabrir, mas ainda acho que uma leitura atenciosa dos links recomendados resolveria. Seria legal ver a sintaxe do Rewrite e ajustar de acordo com a documentação.